# too may redirect wordpress migration

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have made a wordpress website on localhost and it is working fine on localhost. I uploaded it on my hosting after that it started to show me "The page isn’t redirecting properly" error.

I have linked the site to my database

added following in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','https://digitalflipmedia.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://digitalflipmedia.com');
```

changed site url and home url in database.

Here is my htaccess code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?digitalflipmedia\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://digitalflipmedia.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

My website is digitalflipmedia.com

Comment: enable debug mode in wp-config file and check error_log file in your root folder

Answer (score 0):

First of all replace you .htaccess file code with fresh setup htaccess code.

Then open database and change Home ur and base url to site name.

Also change the name of the databse,username,password in the database.

then check it.

Comment: So according to you the sequence of changing this will work?

Answer (score 0):

Download the Database and find localhost website url and replace with main current url. Then open the Admin > Settings > permalinks and click on save.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please explain what you have write. I have database downloaded and i have website at both places localhost and live server but on live server it is not working.

Comment: Ok do you have notepad++.

Comment: Yes, i have notepad++

Comment: Ok open DB in notepad++ and paste the localhost website url in find then paste the live website url in replace then hit replace all.

Comment: Okay let me try this.

Comment: Don't forget replace with two time that means one with / end of the url on both live and local another one is without / at end of the url.

Comment: Sorry my friend i can't now, can you please give me the website url because  the website url above mentioned are not working.

Comment: That is that problem. If the link would work the problem get solved. Its digitalflipmedia.com and its not working.

Comment: Can please  backup .htaccess file and remove from the server. Maybe .htaccess code making this problem.

Comment: Also remove this code in config.php file define('WP_HOME','https://digitalflipmedia.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://digitalflipmedia.com'); because no need these kind of redirection.

Comment: Done. But the problem is still same.

Comment: Ok when did you buyed hosting, domain name ?

Comment: I just puchased my hosting around 1 month ago. And this domain i have is 1 year old.

Comment: Is this problem is because of ssl certificate?

Comment: No, this issue happened because of misconfig, can you please ping me to kumaresandevacc@gmail.com

Comment: Just sent you an email.